# Run multiple instances of an application from inside Geany

Tags: c++, ubuntu, geany

I use Geany in Ubuntu to write C++ code but using IDE standard terminal (pressing F5 to execute code and not opening a new terminal and typing ./a.out).

I can only run one program per time. Is it possible to run 2 or more programs at the same time in Geany?

Comment: duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038164/shell-programming-executing-two-applications-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible using default F5-execute command. If you want to start multiple instances of your application I recommend to use multiple terminals e.g. with [multiterm](http://plugins.geany.org/multiterm.html) or some wrapper. For 2nd opportunity you might want to check https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/